# How to show all margins frames and spacings in the text/equation?

Tags: spacing, margins, line-spacing, displaystyle

The MWE below is showing the margins frame.  This is cool, but not enough for me.  I would like to show the text lines and the spacings around equations (above and below skips, etc).  Is this possible?  Is there an option or package that shows all vertical spacings?

```
\documentclass[11pt,letterpaper,twoside]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[nomath]{lmodern}
\usepackage[total={6in,10in},left=1.5in,top=0.5in,includehead,includefoot,showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage[nodisplayskipstretch]{setspace}
\setstretch{1.1}
\raggedbottom
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{nccmath,amsmath}

\begin{document}

\setlength{\abovedisplayskip}{2ex}
\setlength{\abovedisplayshortskip}{0pt}
\setlength{\belowdisplayskip}{\abovedisplayskip}
\setlength{\belowdisplayshortskip}{\belowdisplayskip}
\setlength{\jot}{3ex}

This is just a test, to see what will happen next and the equation below this dummy text sample:
\begin{align}
    y^2 + x^2 - z^2 = 1
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add

```
\usepackage{lua-visual-debug}
```

and use lualatex then you get

[image]

But really it's easier to debug a textual representation than a visual one so I would add `\showoutput` then with pdflatex you get:

```
Completed box being shipped out [1]
\vbox(686.565+0.0)x592.755
.\vbox(0.0+0.0)x592.755
..\vbox(0.0+0.0)x556.62, glue set - 686.965fil, shifted 36.13501
...\glue -36.135
...\vbox(0.0+0.0)x433.62, glue set - 0.2fil
....\glue 0.0 plus 1.0fil minus 1.0fil
....\rule(0.2+0.0)x433.62
...\glue 12.0
...\glue(\baselineskip) 0.0
...\vbox(0.0+0.2)x433.62
....\glue 0.0 plus 1.0fil minus 1.0fil
....\rule(0.0+0.2)x433.62
...\glue 19.8738
...\glue(\lineskip) 0.0
...\vbox(0.0+0.0)x433.62, glue set - 0.2fil
....\glue 0.0 plus 1.0fil minus 1.0fil
....\rule(0.2+0.0)x433.62
...\glue(\lineskip) 0.0
...\hbox(663.36325+0.0)x556.62, glue set 115.6fil
....\hbox(663.36325+0.0)x0.0, glue set - 0.2fil
.....\glue 0.0 plus 1.0fil minus 1.0fil
.....\rule(663.36325+0.0)x0.2
....\glue 433.62
....\rule(663.36325+0.0)x0.2
....\glue 7.0
....\hbox(663.36325+0.0)x0.0, glue set - 0.2fil
.....\glue 0.0 plus 1.0fil minus 1.0fil
.....\rule(663.36325+0.0)x0.2
....\glue 0.0 plus 1.0fil
....\rule(663.36325+0.0)x0.2
...\glue(\baselineskip) 0.0
...\vbox(0.0+0.0)x433.62, glue set - 0.2fil
....\glue 0.0 plus 1.0fil minus 1.0fil
....\rule(0.2+0.0)x433.62
...\glue 27.46295
...\glue(\baselineskip) 0.0
...\vbox(0.0+0.2)x433.62
....\glue 0.0 plus 1.0fil minus 1.0fil
....\rule(0.0+0.2)x433.62
...\glue 0.0 plus 1.0fil minus 1.0fil
.\glue(\lineskip) 0.0
.\vbox(686.565+0.0)x469.755
..\glue -36.135
..\vbox(722.7+0.0)x433.62, shifted 36.13501
...\vbox(12.0+0.0)x433.62, glue set 5.10452fil
....\glue 0.0 plus 1.0fil
....\hbox(6.89548+0.0)x433.62, glue set 428.145fil
.....\glue 0.0 plus 1.0fil
.....\T1/lmr/m/n/10.95 1
...\glue 19.8738
...\glue(\lineskip) 0.0
...\vbox(663.36325+0.0)x433.62, glue set 603.52058fil
....\write-{}
....\write1{\babel@aux{french}{}}
....\glue(\topskip) 3.45683
....\hbox(7.54317+2.12914)x433.62, glue set 0.11397
.....\hbox(0.0+0.0)x17.0
.....\T1/lmr/m/n/10.95 (+20) T
.....\T1/lmr/m/n/10.95 (+20) h
.....\T1/lmr/m/n/10.95 (+20) i
.....\T1/lmr/m/n/10.95 (+20) s
.....\glue 3.65 plus 1.825 minus 1.21666
.....\T1/lmr/m/n/10.95 (+20) i
.....\T1/lmr/m/n/10.95 (+20) s
.....\glue 3.65 plus 1.825 minus 1.21666
.....\T1/lmr/m/n/10.95 (+20) j
.....\T1/lmr/m/n/10.95 (+20) u
.....\T1/lmr/m/n/10.95 (+20) s
.....\T1/lmr/m/n/10.95 (+20) t
.....\glue 3.65 plus 1.825 minus 1.21666
.....\T1/lmr/m/n/10.95 (+20) a
.....\glue 3.65 plus 1.825 minus 1.21666
.....\T1/lmr/m/n/10.95 (+20) t
.....\T1/lmr/m/n/10.95 (+20) e
.....\T1/lmr/m/n/10.95 (+20) s
.....\T1/lmr/m/n/10.95 (+20) t
.....\T1/lmr/m/n/10.95 (+20) ,
.....\glue 3.65 plus 1.82681 minus 1.21544
.....\T1/lmr/m/n/10.95 (+20) t
.....\T1/lmr/m/n/10.95 (+20) o
.....\glue 3.65 plus 1.825 minus 1.21666
.....\T1/lmr/m/n/10.95 (+20) s
.....\T1/lmr/m/n/10.95 (+20) e
.....\T1/lmr/m/n/10.95 (+20) e
.....\glue 3.65 plus 1.825 minus 1.21666
.....\T1/lmr/m/n/10.95 (+20) w
.....\T1/lmr/m/n/10.95 (+20) h
.....\T1/lmr/m/n/10.95 (+20) a
.....\T1/lmr/m/n/10.95 (+20) t
.....\glue 3.65 plus 1.825 minus 1.21666
.....\T1/lmr/m/n/10.95 (+20) w
.....\T1/lmr/m/n/10.95 (+20) i
.....\T1/lmr/m/n/10.95 (+20) l
.....\T1/lmr/m/n/10.95 (+20) l
.....\glue 3.65 plus 1.825 minus 1.21666
.....\T1/lmr/m/n/10.95 (+20) h
.....\T1/lmr/m/n/10.95 (+20) a
.....\T1/lmr/m/n/10.95 (+20) p
.....\T1/lmr/m/n/10.95 (+20) p
.....\kern0.30417
.....\T1/lmr/m/n/10.95 (+20) e
.....\T1/lmr/m/n/10.95 (+20) n
.....\glue 3.65 plus 1.825 minus 1.21666
.....\T1/lmr/m/n/10.95 (+20) n
.....\T1/lmr/m/n/10.95 (+20) e
.....\T1/lmr/m/n/10.95 (+20) x
.....\T1/lmr/m/n/10.95 (+20) t
.....\glue 3.65 plus 1.825 minus 1.21666
.....\T1/lmr/m/n/10.95 (+20) a
.....\T1/lmr/m/n/10.95 (+20) n
.....\T1/lmr/m/n/10.95 (+20) d
.....\glue 3.65 plus 1.825 minus 1.21666
.....\T1/lmr/m/n/10.95 (+20) t
.....\T1/lmr/m/n/10.95 (+20) h
.....\T1/lmr/m/n/10.95 (+20) e
.....\glue 3.65 plus 1.825 minus 1.21666
.....\T1/lmr/m/n/10.95 (+20) e
.....\T1/lmr/m/n/10.95 (+20) q
.....\T1/lmr/m/n/10.95 (+20) u
.....\T1/lmr/m/n/10.95 (+20) a
.....\T1/lmr/m/n/10.95 (+20) t
.....\T1/lmr/m/n/10.95 (+20) i
.....\T1/lmr/m/n/10.95 (+20) o
.....\T1/lmr/m/n/10.95 (+20) n
.....\glue 3.65 plus 1.825 minus 1.21666
.....\T1/lmr/m/n/10.95 (+20) b
.....\kern0.30417
.....\T1/lmr/m/n/10.95 (+20) e
.....\T1/lmr/m/n/10.95 (+20) l
.....\T1/lmr/m/n/10.95 (+20) o
.....\kern-0.30418
.....\T1/lmr/m/n/10.95 (+20) w
.....\glue 3.65 plus 1.825 minus 1.21666
.....\T1/lmr/m/n/10.95 (+20) t
.....\T1/lmr/m/n/10.95 (+20) h
.....\T1/lmr/m/n/10.95 (+20) i
.....\T1/lmr/m/n/10.95 (+20) s
.....\glue 3.65 plus 1.825 minus 1.21666
.....\T1/lmr/m/n/10.95 (+20) d
.....\T1/lmr/m/n/10.95 (+20) u
.....\T1/lmr/m/n/10.95 (+20) m
.....\T1/lmr/m/n/10.95 (+20) m
.....\kern-0.30418
.....\T1/lmr/m/n/10.95 (+20) y
.....\kern-0.40515 (right margin)
.....\glue(\rightskip) 0.0
....\penalty 200
....\glue(\baselineskip) 5.28778
....\hbox(7.54317+2.12914)x433.62, glue set 372.72693fil
.....\T1/lmr/m/n/10.95 t
.....\T1/lmr/m/n/10.95 e
.....\T1/lmr/m/n/10.95 x
.....\T1/lmr/m/n/10.95 t
.....\glue 3.65 plus 1.825 minus 1.21666
.....\T1/lmr/m/n/10.95 s
.....\T1/lmr/m/n/10.95 a
.....\T1/lmr/m/n/10.95 m
.....\T1/lmr/m/n/10.95 p
.....\T1/lmr/m/n/10.95 l
.....\T1/lmr/m/n/10.95 e
.....\penalty 10000
.....\glue 3.65 plus 1.825 minus 1.21666
.....\T1/lmr/m/n/10.95 :
.....\penalty 10000
.....\kern-1.52205 (right margin)
.....\glue(\parfillskip) 0.0 plus 1.0fil
.....\glue(\rightskip) 0.0
....\penalty 10000
....\glue(\abovedisplayskip) 9.42902
....\glue -14.14352
....\glue 0.0
....\glue(\baselineskip) 16.50247
....\hbox(10.472+4.48807)x433.62, display
.....\glue(\tabskip) 177.4674
.....\hbox(10.472+4.48807)x78.68518
......\glue 0.0 plus 1.0fil
......\hbox(10.472+4.48807)x0.0
.......\vbox(10.472+4.48807)x0.0
........\kern 0.0
........\hbox(10.472+4.48807)x0.0
.........\rule(10.472+4.48807)x0.0
......\hbox(9.67673+2.12917)x78.68518
.......\mathon
.......\hbox(9.67673+2.12917)x78.68518
........\OML/cmm/m/it/10.95 y
........\kern0.39287
........\hbox(5.15556+0.0)x4.75006, shifted -4.52116
.........\OT1/cmr/m/n/8 2
........\glue(\medmuskip) 2.43329 plus 1.21664 minus 2.43329
........\OT1/cmr/m/n/10.95 +
........\glue(\medmuskip) 2.43329 plus 1.21664 minus 2.43329
........\OML/cmm/m/it/10.95 x
........\hbox(5.15556+0.0)x4.75006, shifted -4.52116
.........\OT1/cmr/m/n/8 2
........\glue(\medmuskip) 2.43329 plus 1.21664 minus 2.43329
........\OMS/cmsy/m/n/10.95 ^^@
........\glue(\medmuskip) 2.43329 plus 1.21664 minus 2.43329
........\OML/cmm/m/it/10.95 z
........\kern0.48158
........\hbox(5.15556+0.0)x4.75006, shifted -4.52116
.........\OT1/cmr/m/n/8 2
........\glue(\thickmuskip) 3.04161 plus 3.04161
........\OT1/cmr/m/n/10.95 =
........\glue(\thickmuskip) 3.04161 plus 3.04161
........\OT1/cmr/m/n/10.95 1
.......\mathoff
.....\glue(\tabskip) 0.0
.....\hbox(10.472+4.48807)x0.0
......\hbox(0.0+0.0)x0.0
.......\mathon
.......\hbox(0.0+0.0)x0.0
.......\mathoff
......\glue 0.0 plus 1.0fil
.....\glue(\tabskip) 177.4674
.....\hbox(10.472+4.48807)x0.0
......\kern -177.4674
......\kern 177.4674
......\hbox(10.472+4.48807)x0.0, glue set - 13.9919fil
.......\glue 0.0 plus 1.0fil minus 1.0fil
.......\hbox(10.472+4.48807)x13.9919
........\hbox(10.472+4.48807)x0.0
.........\vbox(10.472+4.48807)x0.0
..........\kern 0.0
..........\hbox(10.472+4.48807)x0.0
...........\rule(10.472+4.48807)x0.0
........\hbox(8.2125+2.73749)x13.9919
.........\T1/lmr/m/n/10.95 (
.........\T1/lmr/m/n/10.95 1
.........\kern 0.0
.........\T1/lmr/m/n/10.95 )
.....\glue(\tabskip) 0.0
....\penalty 10000
....\glue 0.0
....\penalty 0
....\glue(\belowdisplayskip) 9.42902
....\glue -4.48807
....\glue 0.0 plus 1.0fil
....\glue 0.0
....\glue 0.0 plus 0.0001fil
...\glue(\baselineskip) 27.46295
...\hbox(0.0+0.0)x433.62
```

which shows you the size of every box and glue node on the page.

In particular the sequence of vertical nodes after the line `text sample :` and before the math display is:

```
....\penalty 10000
....\glue(\abovedisplayskip) 9.42902
....\glue -14.14352
....\glue 0.0
....\glue(\baselineskip) 16.50247
....\hbox(10.472+4.48807)x433.62, display
```

Comment: The second solution is pretty kryptic to me.  It's very hard to understand what's going on in there.

Comment: @Cham you get used to it.  concentrate on the smaller fragment that I put at the end.  there is a \nobreak penalty then `\abovedisplayskip` added 9.43pt (after accounting for the depth of the line above and the height of the line being added, then there is a negative space of -14.14pt (amsmath adjustment) and a skip of 0pt (again added by amsmath) then tex's baselineskip calculation added 16.5pt, then comes the math display